# Performance gain of GPU when learning DNNs

Tags: gpu, hardware

Currently, I learn deep neural networks on my CPU (i7-6700K) using TensorFlow without AVX2 enabled. The networks need about 3 weeks to be learned. Therefore, I am searching for a (cheap) way to speed up this process. Is it better to compile TensorFlow enabling AVX2 or to buy a cheap[1] GPU like the GeForce GTX 1650 Super (about 180€ and 1408 CUDA cores)? What is the estimated performance gain of using a cheap[1] GPU?

[1] Cheap compared to current top edge GPUs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 years ago the rule of thumb was: *About 15 times faster*

Your CPU does 113 GFlops on float operations ([source](https://techgage.com/article/intels-skylake-core-i7-6700k-a-performance-look/)) and your GPU does 3 Tflops ([source](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-1650.c3366)).

My bet: somewhere between 15 and 30 times faster

Comment: Thank you. Seems like it is totally worth 180€... Is there any estimation on how AVX2 will influence learning times?